Use swaggerhub CLI with azure pipelines
I am trying to do the same thing as I do here with powershell through an azure pipelines file :
PS C:\PathI> 
swaggerhub configure
? SwaggerHub URL: https://api.swaggerhub.com
? API Key: "my key value"
api:update "X/AsyncSpec/3.0.0" -f "path.yaml"
I would do that with azure pipelines
- script: |
    cd "path"
    swaggerhub configure
    https://api.swaggerhub.com
    $(SWAGGERHUB_API_KEY)
    swaggerhub api:update x/AsyncSpec/3.0.0 -f "path.yaml"
  displayName: 'Update API documentation'

I would like it to work as powershell that means :
- do the configure method
- update the documentation

According to swaggerhub configure command, you can set these as environment variables: SWAGGERHUB_URL, SWAGGERHUB_API_KEY. These take priority over config settings.
So we can set the environment variables SWAGGERHUB_URLand SWAGGERHUB_API_KEY in the pipeline to avoid using the swaggerhub configure command directly.
Sample YAML:
trigger:
- none
pool:
   vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  SWAGGERHUB_URL: 'https://api.swaggerhub.com'
  SWAGGERHUB_API_KEY: '$(swaggerhubApiKey)' # Ensure this is set in your pipeline variables

steps:
- script: npm i -g swaggerhub-cli
  displayName: 'Install swaggerhub-cli'

- script: |
      cd "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/folder/path/to/your/file"
      swaggerhub api:update "X/AsyncSpec/3.0.0" -f "test.yaml"
  displayName: 'Update API documentation'
  env:
    SWAGGERHUB_URL: $(SWAGGERHUB_URL)
    SWAGGERHUB_API_KEY: $(SWAGGERHUB_API_KEY)

Please set the swaggerhubApiKey as a secret pipeline variable:

